# Multiple Canvas Sizes in one PSD (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm working on a favicon which needs to have multiple sizes.

Right now, I have a PSD file for each size, e.g., `16x16.psd`, `24x24.psd`, ..., `64x64.psd`.
After I'm done drawing them, I export each size and combine them into the ICO file format.

What I'm wondering is whether Photoshop (CS5 in my case) will allow me to consolidate all of these files with different canvas sizes into one PSD.

I suspect that I can't do this directly, so I would appreciate any advice as to how to best manage files when implementing something like a favicon; i.e., something that doesn't necessarily downscale well automatically.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design. Per the FAQ, this question is off-topic and would normally be closed. But since you got answers, and those answers received upvotes, I am going to leave it open but only as community wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are right you cant do this directly, what you have to do is make a PSD which have bigger dimension such as `100x100` and put all your icons in that particular psd, make separate group folders of your icons like for `16x16` and `24x24` when you need to work on `16x16` just slice them and use it. by this all your icon will enjoy together in a single PSD :P

Comment: This is *exactly* what I needed. Layer-based slices are awesome. Thanks!